# The probability of at least 18 successes in 20 trials, binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A vaccine, which is surrently in use, is known to be 80% effective.  A pharmaceutical company has developed a new vaccine and the company claims 90% of the people given the new vaccine will develop the immunity.  Suppose the claim of the company is true, and the newly developed vaccine is given to 20 people. 
What is the probability that at least 18 people will develop the immunity?

*Progress*: $n=20$, $p=.9$. $x=18,19,20$, $q=.1$ 
What is my next step in figuring this out?
Do I have to do the $n!/(n-x)!p^xq^{n-x}$ for each value of $x$?

Comment: how so?  like how do you mean?

Comment: OP, adding "help please" in the middle of the title kindly edited by another user won't help the visibility of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Progress: $n=20, p=.9, x\in 18,19,20, q=.1$
>
> What is my next step in figuring this out? Do I have to do the $n!/(n−x)! p^x q^{n−x}$  for each value of $x$?

Yes.  More correctly your model is a Binomial Distribution so:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x) & = \dfrac{n!\,p^x\, q^{n-x} }{x!\, (n-x)!} \\[2ex] \mathsf P(X\geq 18) & = \dfrac{20!\,(0.9)^{18}\, (0.1)^{2} }{18!\, 2!} +\dfrac{20!\,(0.9)^{19}\, (0.1)^{1} }{19!\, 1!} +\dfrac{20!\,(0.9)^{20}\, (0.1)^{0} }{20!\, 0!}\end{align}$$

Simplify and evaluate.

Comment: new question...

Comment: experience has shown that 1/200 of all dvds produced by a certain machine are defective.  if a quality control technician randomly test 50 dvds, find the prob that at most one is defective.  n=50, p=.005, x=0,1 q=.995.  when I run the numbers through for 0 and 1 I keep getting 0, as .005^50=0 which would make everything 0.  lost on this one